# Correct way to use LBS_NODATA with CListBox

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, listbox

I am trying to create a `CListBox` that can display more than tens of thousands of items(strings).

In the MSDN [List-box styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/styles-used-by-mfc?view=msvc-170#list-box-styles), it says `LBS_NODATA` should be used when the count of items in the list box exceeds 1,000.

> Specifies a no-data list box. Specify this style when the count of items in the list box will exceed one thousand. A no-data list box must also have the `LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` style, but must not have the `LBS_SORT` or `LBS_HASSTRINGS` style.

So I tried the following: (added `LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` and removed `LBS_SORT` and `LBS_HASSTRINGS`)

```
myListbox.Create((WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD | WS_HSCROLL | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | LBS_NODATA | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED) & ~(LBS_SORT | LBS_HASSTRINGS), CRect(400, 40, 3400, 1140), this, 12345);
```

But it does not show anything if I try to add some string: `myListbox.AddString(_T("some string"))`.

How can I correctly create and use `CListBox` that can show a large number of strings?

Comment: Your problem is, "no data" listboxes don't store data. All you have is the item number - you have to draw the item yourself by handling `WM_MEASUREITEM` and `WM_DRAWITEM`. As an aside, the note about 1,000 items was probably written in 1987, when memory was scarce. It may not be worth bothering about these days.

Comment: How do you expect to add a string to a list-box that not `LBS_HASSTRINGS` ? You should insert the item and then call `SetItemData()`. The "data" would be some pointer  or index to a structure you maintain yourself. And you have to override the `DrawItem()` member (`WM_DRAWITEM` message handler).

Comment: Check the code in `CListBox::DrawItem()` documentation, you really have to paint the text and cater for every combination of items' states. No "standard" drawing (providing the data yourself of course) unfortunately, as with virtual list-view controls.

Comment: Seems I was wrong, `LBS_NODATA` list-boxes store no data at all, so you must set the items count by sending the `LB_SETCOUNT` message (didn't find some CListBox::SetCount() method in the documentation, but it's easy). Your `DeawItem()` implementation should be drawing the item based only on the `itemID` member of the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` structure, not the `itemData` one.

Comment: Displaying tens of thousands of items in a list box would provide a rather poor user experience. Large collection of items certainly requires a different representation, at least something like a folded tree view.

Comment: if it is owner draw it means that you must render it yourself.

Comment: For large lists, I usually prefer to use a "virtual" ListView instead of a "no data" ListBox